# Device busy when reading from tape drive with tar

Tags: tar, tapedrive, lto

When I try to read a tar from tape with `tar tvbf 2048 /dev/nst0`, it returns:

```
tar: /dev/nst0: Cannot read: Device or resource busy
tar: At beginning of tape, quitting now
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

And `lsof | grep st0` returns nothing.

All commands works with mt works. If I try with strace:

```
...
open("/dev/nst0", O_RDONLY)             = 3
read(3, 0x7ff16eb8f000, 1048576)        = -1 EBUSY (Device or resource busy)
...
```

The tape drive has the latest firmware. The tape drive is an IBM ULTRIUM-HH6 and the firmware is F9A1.

Answer (score 4):

- Did you also write with the same block size?
- Did you rewind beforereading?
- Does `mt -f /dev/nst0 status` work?
- Are you chaining `dd`  with `tar` or just using tar as you wrote? There is a quirk when using tar piping and $TAPE environment variable. see below.

Sometimes you issue a command, it fails, there is no noise from the drive, but the tape is not in "rewound" state anymore. Try implicit rewind before each command.

Do a test with another tape (run the commands immediately after each other:
cd /path/to files
mt -f /dev/nst0 rewind; tar -b 2048 -c -f /dev/nst0 *
mt -f /dev/nst0 rewind; tar -b 2048 -t -f /dev/nst0

Btw if you don't want to pass -f /dev/nst0 all the time add `export TAPE=/dev/nst0` in your .bashrc. Keep in mind that if you have this variable tar will prefer the tape drive over stdin/stdout. So this will return "Device or resource busy"

```
export TAPE=/dev/nst0
mt rewind ; tar -b 128 -c *|dd of=$TAPE bs=64K
```

... because both dd and tar are trying to open the tape drive. The correct way to pipe tar is by passing `-f -`:

```
mt rewind ; tar -b 128 -c -f - *|dd of=$TAPE bs=64K
```

Also I'm not sure if this block size will work well. [In this document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E38452_01/en/LTO6_Vol5_E1/LTO6_Vol5_E1.pdf) you can read:

> A block size **no larger** than 256 KB (262144 bytes) is strongly
> recommended when working with HP-UX and tape or VTL devices.

So try dropping the block size to 256KiB or even 128KiB (That's tar -b 512 or -b 256 respectively).